# Different answer with passing argv statements

Tags: c, xcode, eclipse

Hi I ran this on Eclipse and cannot not get the answers on the test;

```
fun is good
my food
2 x 4 = 8
```

Heres the code from the test.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    printf("%s %s %s\n", argv[4], argv[2], argv[3]);
    printf("%c%c %c%s\n", **argv, (*argv)[1], *argv[4], argv[3] + 1);
    printf("%d x %d = %c", strlen(*argv + 2), argc - 1, *(*(argv+1)+2));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

In eclipse I'm getting:

```
good CS800 is
/U gs
51 x 5 = p
```

In Xcode I'm getting:

```
good CS800 is
/U gs
118 x 5 = p
```

Thank you if you can help me understand why I might be getting this.

**Edit**:

I'm passing the words -> `myprog CS800 is good fun`

Comment: what are you passing?

Comment: Sorry I'm passing the words ->  myprog CS800 is good fun

Comment: `argv[0]` is going to the name of the executable or empy if not available so in the first `printf` you need to add one to each index.

Comment: how do you add 1 to **argv - Sorry I'm a total beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argv[0] is the name of your program, so here's what they'd be in your example:

argv[0] = name of your executable

argv[1] = "myprog"

argv[2] = "CS800"

argv[3] = "is"

argv[4] = "good"

argv[5] = "fun"

so you need to increment all your numbers by 1, e.g. change:

```
printf("%s %s %s\n", argv[4], argv[2], argv[3]);
```

to:

```
printf("%s %s %s\n", argv[5], argv[3], argv[4]);
```

EDIT: I haven't tested this, but try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("%s %s %s\n", argv[5], argv[3], argv[4]);
printf("%c%c %c%s\n", *(*(argv+1)), (*(argv+1))[1], *argv[5], argv[4] + 1);
printf("%d x %d = %c", strlen(*(argv + 3)), argc - 2, *(*(argv+2)+2));
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: ok that solves the first line though I'm having trouble adding one to these -> **argv or (*argv)[1] or strlen(*argv + 2) or *(*(argv+1)+2)) how would you add 1 to those?

Comment: Just change (*(argv+1)) to (*(argv+2)), and so on.

Comment: Sorry that argv structure isn't in my code? I'm trying to add 1 in various ways though it's not working. I can only get the 1st line to work and "food to work though the rest I have no idea. when I add 1 to strlen(*argv + 2) it gives 117

Comment: I managed to fix these as well "argc - 1, *(*(argv+1)+2))" to argc - 2, *(*(argv+2)+2)); which gave me 4 = 8 so now my code is.  fun is good
/U food
118 x 4 = 8

Comment: See updated answer, I haven't tested it, but you'll see the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Simplicity, you can see array[i][j] as * ( *(array+i)+j) ,they are the same. it lies on different situation that which one is easier to understand.

And, as operator,[] has higher priority  than * .

The first line is easy to explian. ignore.

The second line:

```
printf("%c%c %c%s\n", **argv, (*argv)[1], *argv[4], argv[3] + 1);
```

**argv is argv[0][0]，the first letter of your program's name;

(*argv)[1] is argv[0][1], the second letter of your program's name;

*argv[4] is argv[4][0], the first letter of "good";

argv[3] + 1 is a pointer to argv[3][1],but %s turn it to a string, which is actually "s\0".

Let's see the third line.

```
printf("%d x %d = %c", strlen(*argv + 2), argc - 1, *(*(argv+1)+2));
```

argc -1 is 6 -1 ,it turns out 5;

*( *(argv+1)+2)) is argv[1][2], the letter "p";

*argv is argv[0],which is a pointer to a string,and *argv+2 will be a string starting with the argv and the rest. strlen(*argv+2) equals strlen(argv[0]) if the strlen(argv[0]) was more than 2.

So I think the difference between two output is because argv[0] is different.In other word,the names of your two program is different.

Comment: I like your description. I'm going to go over it a bit to let it soak in how it works.

Comment: I don't know the the name of executable file generated by your eclipse and xcode, which is *argv[0],you'd better check them.

Answer (score 0):

ok I managed to fix it but just by a fluke though the first code should work if argv[0] is passed somehow. 
But to get the result I did this:

```
/* printf("%s %s %s\n", argv[4], argv[2], argv[3]); */
/* became */
printf("%s %s %s\n", argv[5], argv[3], argv[4]);

/* printf("%c%c %c%s\n", **argv, (*argv)[1], *argv[4], argv[3] + 1); */
/* became */
printf("%c%c %c%s\n", **(argv + 1), (*(argv+1))[1], *argv[5], argv[4] + 1);

/* printf("%d x %d = %c", strlen(*argv + 2), argc - 1, *(*(argv+1)+2)); */
/* became */
printf("%d x %d = %c", strlen(*(argv+4)), argc - 2, *(*(argv+2)+2));
                          /* this I added 4 to argv */
```

Comment: If you can get it to work without +1 you've solved it. But beats me how to do that....

Comment: I suppose to change strlen(*(argv+4)) to strlen(*(argv+2) + 2) or other thing, not to conside the string argv[0], because it's harder to examine the name of your executable file generated by a complex IDE sometimes than the word you pass like argv[1] and so on.